# Parse.Com : How to get all data when certain column is null?

Tags: parse-platform

I have plan to sync from my parse.com data to my postgreSql local database with JS API. To do that, i have to get all data that have null value for Column last_sync (it's mean that data did not syncing with local database).

Please help me how to get all data that last_sync is null?

Answer (score 5):

You're not stating what language you're using, but this is a solution for Android:

```
query.whereDoesNotExist("last_sync");
```

This will constrain the query to only those records that don't have a value set in last_sync

For JavaScript:

```
query.doesNotExist("last_sync");
```

Answer (score 0):

For Objective-C:

```
[query whereKeyDoesNotExist:@"last_sync"];
```

Comment: sorry my question is for JS API not for IOS

Comment: That may have been your intent, but when people search for how to do this, regardless of platform, this question on StackOverflow is the top result. So since I know it's the top result for Obj-C (because I searched for this) I decided to add it as an answer once I found it.